# How to access any icon in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have tried the following method still it shows Unresolved reference: Calculate error

Icon needed -
[calculate](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Acalculate%3A)

`import androidx.compose.material.Icon Icon( Icons.Rounded.Calculate,  contentDescription = "" )`

Dependency used :

```
dependencies{ implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"}
```

Comment: Do you have `Calculate` import? `import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Calculate`

Comment: I tried it this also shows Unresolved reference: Calculate as error in import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Calculate,
            contentDescription = "Icon",
            tint = Color.White
        )
```

Comment: I tried your answer but error dint gone :(

Comment: Maybe you need to clean your project?

Comment: Yeah you got the exact point cleaning project worked for me thank you :-)